# How do I make it so my discord bot only take inputs from the person that started the command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
    @client.command()
    async def submitcluetest(ctx):
         await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}Check your dms!")
         await ctx.author.send('Submit your answer here, all lowercase. Do not reveal this to anyone else if you got it right, everyone who solves it gets a special role :smirk:')
         message = await client.wait_for('message')
         if message.content == 'twopeople':
         await ctx.send('correct answer')
     else
         await ctx.send('try again')
```

This is my code right now. The problem is that once someone starts the command and tries to input their answer, someone else could type something and interrupt them. I would like `message.content` only be detected by the user. I tried using `message.author.content` or `author.message.content` but that still wouldn't work.

Comment: You essentially need to have a variable in your bot that records the id of the person upon the initial command. After that you can ignore messages where `ctx.author.id` doesn't match what is recorded.

Comment: Hello, there's pretty much nothing to do with [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/) in your code. So next time be sure to **not** tag something that not relevant to your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to check the author sent a message or someone sent a message you can create a function which returns `True` if author sent a message or return `False` if someone sent a message. Just pass the new function you created  as parameter in the `client.wait_for` function so that your bot wait till the author sends the message in the channel. You can also specify a timeout parameter which make the bot to know how much much time it should wait in seconds
**You can understand this in the below example**

```py
@client.command()
async def submitcluetest(ctx):
     def check(m):
          return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
     await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}Check your dms!")
     await ctx.author.send('Submit your answer here, all lowercase. Do not reveal this to anyone else if you got it right, everyone who solves it gets a special role :smirk:')
     try:
          message = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=120, check=check)
     except asyncio.TimeoutError:  
          await ctx.send("You didn't entered in time.Please answer at next time!")
          return
     else:
          if message.content == 'twopeople':
            await ctx.send('correct answer')
          else
            await ctx.send('try again')
```

Comment: Hey there Daniel! Instead of simply placing a 'chunk' of code here, try to explain what the new sections of code do, that way others who read your code will understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: oh okay i will edit my answer to understand the new part of code

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda expression for the check.
`message = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author)`